# How do i give a BigDecimal variable a value in a method?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Like the title says im trying to give the BigDecimal Variable a value of zero "(0)" or any other number in a method. I know that local variables in a method dont have a default value unlike a member variable.  But how do i do it? I'm new to java.

Thanks in advance!

```
  private BigDecimal validateValue(BigDecimal valueControl){
    BigDecimal valueZero(0); // here i'm having my issue. 
    if(valueControl.compareTo(valueZero) > 0){
      valueZero = valueControl;
    } else if(valueControl.compareTo(valueZero) < 0) {
      valueZero = valueControl;
    } return valueZero;
   }
```

Problems:

> ';' expected
> Variable 'valueZero' might not have been initialized

Comment: Side note: You are assigning the same value (`valueControl`) to `valueZero` in both branches of the *if* condition. Re-think on what you want to return when `valueControl` is lesser than 0 and when it is greater than 0. If you want to return the same, then you can rewrite the *if* to compare against 0 (`== 0`).

Comment: Regarding your `(0)`, be careful to not pass a `float`/`double` to the constructor of `BigDecimal` if your goal is accuracy. Those floating-point types trade away accurate for speed of execution. So pass decimal numbers as strings to the constructor.

Comment: Your conditions are useless, for example, `private BigDecimal validateValue(BigDecimal valueControl) {
    return valueControl;
}` return the same result of your code

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize your local variable `valueZero`.

You can do so using the constant, [`BigDecimal.ZERO`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ZERO).

```
BigDecimal valueZero = BigDecimal.ZERO;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 private BigDecimal validateValue(BigDecimal valueControl){
    BigDecimal valueZero = new BigDecimal("0"); 
    if(valueControl.compareTo(valueZero) > 0){
      valueZero = valueControl;
    } else if(valueControl.compareTo(valueZero) < 0) {
      valueZero = valueControl;
    } return valueZero;
   }
```

You need to instantiate your variable valueZero using the "new" keyword since you're not using a primitive type otherwise java can't know what is valueZero, ence your error message

Comment: You don't **need** to use `new`.  There are predefined constants for 0, 1, 2, 10.  Also the static `BigDecimal.valueOf(...)` methods are preferable.

Comment: We are talking about someone that apparently doesn't know about variable assignement, ence why I prefered to give a more general/basic solution, because most of the time when you initialize a non-primitive type, you use "new"
Also if he happens to want to initialize with a value different from Zero (like 12.84), using the predefined constant won't help him and even maybe disturb him.

Comment: Fine.  But don't say that the OP >>needs<< to do it.  Because that is incorrect.